# Mysql server installation

Tags: mysql, installation

I am trying to install mysql 5.1.42 and after running below line

sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password

I get this error:

/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!

I have created mysqld.sock and gave permission to it too. but still get the same error.

can anyone help

thanks

Comment: Is mysqld actually running? You could also give us some clues, such as which OS you're using. BTW, there must be no whitespace between the "-p" and the password.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that mysql is really running?
Do a

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

to check this.
Also it is often easier to connect via TCP/IP than via sockets:

```
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that your client and server have different ideas to where the socket lives.

If you have a /proc file system, finding where the server has put the socket is quite easy.  The output from:

```
ps -elf | grep mysqld
```

should include the process id of one of the mysqld server threads (any will do).  Then look in /procto see where the socket has been written:

```
sudo ls -l /proc/NNN/fd
```

where NNN is the process id from the "ps" call.

Once you know where the socket is, pass its location in the connect string:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -S /path/to/mysqld.sock -ppassword
```

The socket location is normally specified in the mysql.cnf file (/etc/mysql/mysql.cnf or /etc/mysql.cnf or whatever), in the section headed "[mysqld]".   If there is no socket entry in there, then the server will use the compiled in default which is /tmp/mysql.sock.  You can always stop (or kill) the server, and add an explicit socket entry into the config file like:

```
[mysqld]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

It is worth adding the same to the [client] section so all the client tools have the same idea.